# ¿Como cambiar texto de un Jlabel dependiendo de un entero random sin recargar la aplicacion? -- Java Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy desarrollando un programa en Netbeans similar a ¿Quien quiere ser millonario?
Manejo mis preguntas guardarndolas  en variables string y segun el aleatorio quiero que se pongan en el label:

```java
aleatorioJuego = (int) (Math.random() * (maxJuego)) + min;

            switch (aleatorioJuego) {
                case 1:
                    quest.setText(preg1);
                    lblres1.setText(resPreg1A);
                    lblres2.setText(resPreg1B);
                    lblres3.setText(resPreg1C);
                    lblres4.setText(resPreg1D);
                    respCorrJuego = resPreg1C;

                    break;
                case 2:
                    quest.setText(preg2);
                    lblres1.setText(resPreg2A);
                    lblres2.setText(resPreg2B);
                    lblres3.setText(resPreg2C);
                    lblres4.setText(resPreg2D);
                    respCorrJuego = resPreg2C;

                    break;
```

Asi, hasta el case 15

Ahora, cuando le doy al boton y es la respuesta correcta, hago lo siguiente:

```java
if (resPreg3B.equals(respCorrJuego)) {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Respuesta Correcta!", "CORRECTO!!", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
            nRespJuego = nRespJuego + 1;
            confOp = confOp++;
            points = points + 1500;
            lblpoints.setText("Puntos: " + points);
```

Sale un JoptionPane que me indica que la respuesta es correcta, pero no cambia el Random, por lo tanto no cambia el texto de la pregunta y las respuestas.
Quiero  saber como al darle al yes del JOptionPane se vuelva a dar el random y se vuelva a ejecutar el Switch.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Échale un ojo a [¿Como preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Sin código ni una muestra de que lo intentaste poco se te ayudara

Comment: Sin saber cómo está puesto ese código en tu clase, el camino es entonces volver a generar el aleatorio tal cual lo hiciste, validarlo contra la lista de valores que ya usaste (te toca crear y actualizar esa lista, no la tienes) y validar la generación del nuevo aleatorio de acuerdo a alguna condición de parada que elijas

Comment: @Alfabravo ¿Me podrías dar  un ejemplo de como hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

No estoy seguro que tu programe funcione, al menos no veo lógica en

```
if (resPreg3B.equals(respCorrJuego)) {
  //tu código
}
```

Porque está comparando la respuesta de la pregunta 3 con la respuesta correcta, ¿Qué sucede si es una pregunta diferente?.

**Te planteo una solución**

1. Creamos una clase con los atributos para la pregunta, alternativas y la respuesta correcta.

```
public class JuegoAtributos {
    private String pregunta;
    private String alternativa1;
    private String alternativa2;
    private String alternativa3;
    private String alternativa4;
    private String respuestaCorrecta;

    //constructor y getter
}
```

2. Creamos un jframe donde desarrollaremos la lógica del juego, para ello hacemos uso del java swing, creando 1 JTextField para la pregunta, 4 JButton para las alternativas, 1 JButton para continuar con la siguiente pregunta y 1 JButton para retirarse del juego.

[image: Interfaz del juego]

Tengamos en cuenta que aparte de generar números aleatorios que corresponden al número de la pregunta que se mostrará en la interfaz, también debemos tener en cuenta que cada número aleatorio generado debe ser diferente esto con el fin de que no nos muestre la misma pregunta 2 veces porque de eso se trata el juego; entonces vamos a crear la clase que extiende de JFrame con los siguientes atributos, que puedes agregar más atributos según las reglas que consideres necesarias en el juego.

```
public class JuegoDePreguntas extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    
    List<JuegoAtributos> listado= new ArrayList<>();
    //Para generar numeros aleatorios no repetidos
    Set<Integer> alreadyUsedNumbers = new HashSet<>();
    String respuestaCorrecta;
    int puntajeAcumulado=0;
}
```

Creamos un método con las preguntas, alternativas y respuesta correcta y añadiremos al arreglo de la clase (sólo voy crear 5 elementos con fines didácticos)

```
public void crearArreglo(){                
        listado.add(new JuegoAtributos("Pregunta 1", "Respuesta 1.1", "Respuesta 1.2", "Respuesta 1.3", "Respuesta 1.4", "Respuesta 1.1"));
        listado.add(new JuegoAtributos("Pregunta 2", "Respuesta 2.1", "Respuesta 2.2", "Respuesta 2.3", "Respuesta 2.4", "Respuesta 2.2"));
        listado.add(new JuegoAtributos("Pregunta 3", "Respuesta 3.1", "Respuesta 3.2", "Respuesta 3.3", "Respuesta 3.4", "Respuesta 3.4"));
        listado.add(new JuegoAtributos("Pregunta 4", "Respuesta 4.1", "Respuesta 4.2", "Respuesta 4.3", "Respuesta 4.4", "Respuesta 4.2"));
        listado.add(new JuegoAtributos("Pregunta 5", "Respuesta 5.1", "Respuesta 5.2", "Respuesta 5.3", "Respuesta 5.4", "Respuesta 5.1"));    
}
```

Creamos el método que va devolver un entero que no se repite para mostrar una pregunta diferente cada vez en la interfaz.

```
public int aleatorioNoRepetido(){
        int devolver=0;
        boolean b=false;
        while(!b){
            int randomNumber=(int) (5 * Math.random());
            if (!alreadyUsedNumbers.contains(randomNumber)){                  
                  alreadyUsedNumbers.add(randomNumber);  
                  b=true;
                  devolver=randomNumber;
            } 
        }
        return devolver;    
 }
```

Método para mostrar la pregunta y alternativas en la interfaz, además de obtener la respuesta correcta para cada pregunta.

```
public void jugar(){        
        int numeroPregunta=aleatorioNoRepetido();
        txtPregunta.setText(listado.get(numeroPregunta).getPregunta());
        btnRespuesta1.setText(listado.get(numeroPregunta).getAlternativa1());
        btnRespuesta2.setText(listado.get(numeroPregunta).getAlternativa2());
        btnRespuesta3.setText(listado.get(numeroPregunta).getAlternativa3());
        btnRespuesta4.setText(listado.get(numeroPregunta).getAlternativa4());
        respuestaCorrecta=listado.get(numeroPregunta).getRespuestaCorrecta();
  }
```

Implementamos el ActionPerformed para cada uno de los 4 botones de las alternativas, es decir la lógica cuando un participante elija una alternativa para cada pregunta; aquí se pueden aumentar más reglas depende lo que tú quieres. Para explicarme mejor aquí puedes desarrollar que pasa si el participante escoge una alternativa incorrecta, cuantos intentos tiene para que pregunta, que sucederá cuando se termine el número de intentos, etc,etc.

```
private void btnRespuesta1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        if(respuestaCorrecta.equals(btnRespuesta1.getText())){ 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Respuesta correcta");
            puntajeAcumulado+=150;
        }
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Respuesta Incorrecta");
 }
```

El ActionPerformed del boton continuar hará que muestre una nueva pregunta en la interfaz siempre y cuando no haya mostrado todas las preguntas posibles

```
private void btnContinuarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        if(alreadyUsedNumbers.size()==5){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Llegaste a la final, Puntaje acumulado: "+puntajeAcumulado);
            btnContinuar.setVisible(false);//ocultamos el boton continuar
        }
        else        
            jugar();
 }
```

El ActionPerformed del boton retirse, de la misma forma añades tus reglas que deseas; para el ejemplo sólo estoy mostrando cuanto puntaje tiene acumulado hasta que decide retirarse.

```
private void btnRetirarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Juego terminado");
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Puntaje acumulado: "+puntajeAcumulado);
}
```

El constructor de la clase llamará a los métodos para iniciar los componentes, crear arreglo de preguntas y mostrar la primera pantalla de la interfaz

```
public JuegoDePreguntas() {
        initComponents();        
        crearArreglo();
        jugar();
}
```

Por último el método main lo único que hace es llamar al constructor de la clase

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
     new JuegoDePreguntas().setVisible(true);
}
```